# .htaccess help needed for redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I redirect both these URL's back to **/blog/** and covering any variations that also include **?page_id** for the first one and **no_redirect** for the second one.

- https://www.example.com/blog/page/10/?page_id=%2Ffeed%2Fatom%2F

and

- https://www.example.com/blog/page/10/?no_redirect=true

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/page/10/\?page_id=%2Ffeed%2Fatom%2F [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/page/10/\?no_redirect=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/? [L,R]
```

EDIT :

here is an another way to redirect everything after the /blog/page/* to /blog/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/page/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/? [L,R]
```

Comment: The above code works for the second rule but not the first.

Comment: I tried the following but it didn't work:


`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/page/10/\?page_id=\d+(?:&|$)[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/page/10/\?no_redirect=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/? [L,R]`

Is there any way of using a blanket statement to cover anything that follows /page/ ? such as /blog/page/*

Comment: I tested the code on my server, both urls are working. But your code (#1cond pattern) isn't correct.

Comment: One the first rule I get this as the result:

`https://www.example.com/blog/page/10/?page_id=/feed/atom/`

and still a 404 page.