# .htaccess help for redirect

Tags: linux, .htaccess

Need some help trying to redirect a domain:

https://www.example.com/blog/page/10/?page_id=%2Ffeed%2Fatom%2F to /blog/

I think the best way is to just redirect anything after /page

The code below is what I'm thinking but I know is not correct:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/page/[0-255]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/? [NC,R=301,L]`

Any advice?

Comment: This has already been answered. what exactly is your problem?

Comment: thanks starkeen. For others looking for the answer it's available on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484786/htaccess-help-needed-for-redirects/36485029?noredirect=1#comment60579873_36485029

Answer (score 0):

> Need some help trying to redirect a domain:

If you are trying to redirect the domain use something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       "http://www\.exampe2\.com\/blog/" [R=301,L]
```

If you want to append the request to the URL use `$1`

If you're rewriting the path to `/blog/` and want to keep the query string use the [QSA] flag ie.

```
RewriteRule /blog/(.*) /blog/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

this will make sure you keep your query string.